# how to play facebook video using url in iphone?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am getting "json" response from facebook api and i want to play video which is share by user.

I am using this code:

```
NSString *path =[[FacebookFeedarray objectAtIndex:(long)clicked.tag] objectForKey:@"source"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES; 
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
[moviePlayer play];
```

And the url is :
https://video.xx.fbcdn.net/hvideo-xta1/v/t42.1790-2/11324750_10153450000004560_1780301857_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjMwMiwicmxhIjo1MTJ9&rl=302&vabr=168&oh=9c64b9ae34e1c1751d41ef2a4c4c220f&oe=555E0678

Answer (score 0):

Add this code too.

```
[moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Try using CustomMoviePlayerViewController in your project available here at https://github.com/BigBadOwl/iStreamer-Download-Manager/blob/master/CustomMoviePlayerViewController.m